# Erro envio de informações ao banco. Formulário de edição

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um formulário de edição de um feed de posts. Quando clico para salvar a edição aparece o seguinte erro:

```
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "title" 
violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (1, 1, null, null, null, 2018-04-24 10:04:55). 
(SQL: update "feeds" set "title" = , "description" = , "updated_at" = 2018- 
04- 24 10:04:55 where "id" = 1)
```

É como se estivesse enviando informações em branco, porém não tem nada em branco.

**feed-update.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <form action="<?php echo action('HomeController@save', $feed->id); ?>" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?> ">
       <h1>Editar Post</h1>
       <b>Publicado por: {{$feed->user->name}} </b><br>


       <b>Título:</b><input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$feed->title}}">
       <br>
       <b>Descrição:</b><input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$feed->description}}">
       <br>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>    
   </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

**HomeController@save**

```
    public function save($idFeed)
    {
       $title = Request()->input('description');
       $description = Request()->input('title');

       $feed = feed::find($idFeed);
       $feed->description = $description;
       $feed->title = $title;
       $feed->save();

       return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os Campos do formulário não possuem o atributo `name`, por isso os mesmos não estão sendo recebidos no controller.
Segue correção:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <form action="<?php echo action('HomeController@save', $feed->id); ?>" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?> ">
       <h1>Editar Post</h1>
       <b>Publicado por: {{$feed->user->name}} </b><br>


       <b>Título:</b><input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$feed->title}}" name="title">
       <br>
       <b>Descrição:</b><input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$feed->description}}" name="description">
       <br>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>    
   </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Outro ponto é a inversão do $title recebendo o campo description.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Comment: Sim, acabei de arrumar.